# Cannot open web socket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I was trying to write a piece of code to open web socket.

```
var ws = null;


var close = function() {
 if (ws) {
  console.log('closing ...');
  ws.close();
 }
}

var onOpen = function() {
 console.log('opening...');
 ws.send('hello. im connected');
};

var onClose = function() {
  console.log('closed');
};

var onMessage = function(event) {
 var data = event.data;
 console.log('message: ' + data);
};

close();

var url = 'ws://localhost:9999';
ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.onopen = onOpen;
ws.onclose = onClose;
ws.onmessage = onMessage;

console.log('ws: ' + ws);


if (ws)
{
 console.log('url:' + ws.url);
 console.log('readyState:' + ws.readyState);
 ws.send(msg);
 }
 else
 alert('no ws');
```

But when seeing the console, the readyState was keep being "CONNECTING", which causes the socket send() command throwing exception.

I tried the extension https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo and get the same issue. The server is pretty simple that accepts incoming socket and write out to console.

There's initial hand shaking but the client's readyState still kept being 0.

Here is the hand shaking:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:9999
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: Qb 15  05 6 Gq 9   26 u0 6
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 8096 C0587|7.
```

Do i have anything specific in the server to let the client be opened?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you parse the handshake on the server side and send back the hash from the two keys?

Comment: do you feel your question has been sufficiently answered? (if so can you select an answer). If not, anything else we can help you with to resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your block showing the handshake is incomplete. There should be a blank line followed by 8 bytes of extra data (or key3).

The server needs to construct a return handshake that will look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r
Upgrade: WebSocket\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:8080\r
Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:9999/\r
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample\r
\r
[16 byte md5 hash]
```

The 16 byte hash that the server returns is calculated as follows:

- take the numbers from the key1 data and convert them to a number. Divide this number by the number of spaces the key1 data. This gives you a 4 byte key1 number.
- do the same thing to the key2 data to get a key2 number.
- create a 16 byte array by packing in key1 number (4 bytes) followed by key2 number (4 bytes) followed by the 8 bytes of extra data received from the client (8 bytes).
- md5 sum the 16 byte array to get a new 16 byte array. This is what is written to the client to finish the handshake response.

Until the server returns a handshake the client will show "CONNECTING".

The server handshake response is described in more detail in section 5.2 of the [WebSockets version 76 standards document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76)

**Update based on second question** (in the answer section):

If all you are trying to do is send data from an extension then you might consider just using a XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) POST request. Since you are getting anything back from the request I suspect latency is not that important for your application. XMLHttpRequest should be easily support for extensions for both firefox and Chrome.

On the other hand, if latency is important, or if your server where the data is being sent is purely a socket server, adding WebSockets support wouldn't be that much more difficult than adding HTTP support (actually, might be easier). And WebSockets support should also be support for extensions in both Chrome and firefox (4.0 and onwards).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I didn't know that this is 2 ways communication.

I was coding an Chrome extension, that opens a socket and send data to a specific application. I made it worked with FF, using below socket:

```
var transportService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsISocketTransportService);
var transport = transportService.createTransport(null,0,"localhost",9999,null);
```

Is there a way that uses similar approach on Chrome? or I have to use WebSocket with 2 ways communication? I dont want to make it complex as I have to modify the receiver application to return a handshake.

Thanks.